# Definition of Power

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, energy, work, power

I wanted to clear my doubts regarding the true definition of power. Imagine a mass falling from a height and reaching the ground thanks to gravity. The power of this event would be the work done by gravity on the mass divided by the amount of time it took to reach the ground.

However another definition of power would be the force applied times the velocity, however since this mass is accelerating, the power would constantly increase until the mass reached the ground.

How do I connect these two definitions of power? Is power force times velocity even when the velocity is constantly changing?

Comment: Have you tried to actually compute these two terms so that you can compare them? The power in the first case is not constant either - the work done increases linearly with distance but the time taken to reach that distance is not a linear function of distance.

Comment: "work (energy)...divided by the amount of time" is a definition of _average_ power during that particular interval of time, but when you say, "the power would constantly increase," you are talking about _instantaneous_ power. You can't define that without using calculus (e.g., as shown in the answers below.)

Answer (score 2):

$$P_\text{avg} = \dfrac{\Delta P}{\Delta t}$$ is the average power, whereas $$P=F\cdot v$$ is the instantaneous power derived from the fact that $P\equiv \dfrac{\mathrm d W}{\mathrm dt}$ where $W$ is the work done

Answer (score 1):

In your example, assuming the right approximations, force is simply given by -

$F = ma$ with the usual terminology. So the force is constant.

The power exerted on the falling object is given by the rate of change of energy.

The definition of energy in terms of force is:

$E = \int F . ds$

again, with the usual notations.

Therefore, power (the rate of change of energy) will be -

$P = \frac{dE}{dt} = \int F. \frac{ds}{dt} = F . v$ which is true because $s = s(t)$ and $F$ is constant.

As [this resource](http://In%20the%20straightforward%20cases%20where%20a%20constant%20force%20moves%20an%20object%20at%20constant%20velocity,%20the%20power%20is%20just%20P%20=%20Fv) says,

> In the straightforward cases where a constant force moves an object at constant velocity, the power is just P = Fv

So the answer depends on the question you are asking.

If you would like to calculate the *instantaneous* power, the product of force and the velocity at that time would indeed be correct.

If you are going to calculate power by taking the difference of the initial and final energies and dividing that by the time difference, that is the *average* power and here, you could calculate it as the force times the *average* velocity measured over the duration of the experiment.

Answer (score 1):

So we know the potential energy converted to kinetic energy is:

$$ U=mgz $$

where $z$ is the vertical coordinate. The power is the rate at which this conversion takes place:

$$ P\equiv \frac{dU}{dt}=mg\frac{dz}{dt}=F_gv_z$$

It's that straight forward. At higher speed, more height is traversed per unit time.

From the kinetic energy side, we have:

$$T=\frac 1 2 mv_z^2 $$

with

$$ P\equiv \frac{dT}{dt}=\frac 1 2 m\frac{d(v_z^2)}{dt}=mv_z\dot  v_z$$

and:

$$ \dot v_z = \frac{F_g} m $$

so that:

$$p= F_gv_z $$

Answer (score 0):

Work done by a mass falling

integral f . dr

however in falling dr is  v(t) dt as dr/dt = r'(t)

So integral f. v(t) dt

Power in this case is the  rate at which work is being done  by gravity on the mass

so d/dt (work) =
d/dt (integral f.v(t) dt)

is obviously f.v(t)